# Need help to set up home server - client network (RedHat 7)

Tags: networking, router, webserver, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have very basic knowledge on networking. I recently purchased a Dell server to do my own development work. I have installed a RedHat Linux server. I am trying to set up a local server client set up.

Here is what I did.

1. Connected the server and client computers to a router
2. Assigned a static IP to ethernet2
3. Opened port 22 as below

   ```
   firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=22/tcp --permanent
   firewall-cmd --reload
   ```

Now I am trying to connect to this server through Putty from a Windows client machine. But I am getting a

> connection timed out

error. What I am missing? Can someone help me to set it up?
I've never used RedHat before.

Comment: You didn't mention whether ssh has been enabled on your Red Hat machine. Run `systemctl enable sshd` and `systemctl start sshd`

Answer (score 0):

By default, redhat 7 comes with firewalld enabled with the ssh service configured in the public zone, which means you can connect through ssh without further configuration

Here are some things you can check:

1. Verify both server and the client are in the same network and they can ping each other.
2. If you thing it's a firewall related issue you can flush all rules with the following command and test again:

   > iptables -F
3. Provide more information to see if we can help (IP addresses, routing table, firewall rules, etc.).

Waiting for your feedback.